# How can I move application windows with shortcut keys to the four quadrants of the screen in Ubuntu Mate 20?

Tags: shortcut-keys, software-recommendation, desktop-environments, window-management

I just installed Ubuntu 20 with the Mate desktop environment. As I have a 4K monitor, I'd like to move application windows quickly using shortcut keys so that four application windows occupy the four quadrants of the screen, like this:

```
+-----------+----------+
| Window 1  | Window 2 |
+-----------+----------+
| Window 3  | Window 4 |
+-----------+----------+
```

<s>However, in Mate it seems it's not possible to do quickly. It's only possible to move a window to the left or right side of the screen with a shortcut key (Super + Left/Right Arrow), but not to the upper left, upper right, lower left or lower right side. This results in cumbersome mousing to fiddle the window sizes before moving them to their respective quadrants.</s>

Which Ubuntu desktop environments have the feature enabling moving a window with a shortcut key to a screen quadrant?

Edit: the premise of the original question was apparently incorrect, as what I want is possible with Ubuntu Mate since version 20, as pointed out by N0rbert in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253284/475595). Therefore I changed the question title so that the accepted answer reflects the question better. The orignal title was "Which desktop environments allow moving application windows with shortcut keys to the four quadrants of the screen?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not read [release notes](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-focal-fossa-release-notes/) of latest Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS release:

> **New Key-bindings**
>
> ...
>
> - Title Window to upper right corner: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>
> - Title Window to upper left corner: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>
> - Title Window to lower right corner: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>
> - Title Window to lower left Corner: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

Note: to restore full set of all these new window management shortcuts one can use the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings unmaximize '<Mod4>Down'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings maximize '<Mod4>Up'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-corner-ne '<Alt><Mod4>Right'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-corner-sw '<Shift><Alt><Mod4>Left'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-side-e '<Mod4>Right'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-corner-se '<Shift><Alt><Mod4>Right'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-center '<Alt><Mod4>c'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-corner-nw '<Alt><Mod4>Left'
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings tile-to-side-w '<Mod4>Left'
```

<sup>They are defined in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_mate-common.gschema.override` file.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is great!